# SSD and Backing up data

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup, ssd

I'm brand new to the world of SSD. I set up TRIM and turned off the various windows 7 hibernation and defrag options, so i think i'm optimized.

Since i've read that the life of a SSD can be questionable, how should I approach backing up data? I'm using 3 hard drives - main SSD - media drive - aux drive with pictures and pagefile. I have been using fbackup previously, but i'm wondering what the best practice is with SSD's for bac

Comment: Your backup strategy has little to do with what type of hard drive you have. Do whatever you were doing before to backup your data.

Comment: what causes the life of a SSD to degrade? is it the reading of data or the writing?

Comment: Writes.  If you have a modern SSD, this shouldn't be a problem for several years unless you're doing lots of heavy writes.  Also, SSDs are *perfect* candidates for pagefiles, unless you're extremely space-constrained.

Comment: What @fideli said.  Storage is storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSDs usually fails rather gracefully as far as I am concerned, and most of the time you want programs and system installed on the SSD and data put on other drives. Thus if you are sticking to the principles, you should not have a need to backup the SSD other than as a tool for OS recovery. And for that you can use windows 7 backup utility & create a disc to make an image of the SSD.

For other backup tools, you can either consider cloud-based backup (like what amazon offer) or the more traditional one. Remember, **two sites, two copies, two type of media.**

Comment: I have several large programs that i need to install, each 3+GB's. Do i copy the install files to the SSD and install to the SSD from there? Or should i keep the file on my 2nd hard drive, and install to the SSD? Basically, i'm going to install the program to the SSD, but from where should I install from?

Comment: If I were you I would copy it to a magnetic disk and install it onto the SSD. The space on SSD is scarce...